# Curve-fitting sinusoidal data in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to curve-fit sinusoidal data so that I can analyze the extreme minima/maxima. Below you will see the graph of all the data plotted, and then the x-axis limited to one extreme maximum.

#### All data

[image: All data]

#### One maximum

[image: One maximum]

```
def func(x, a, b, h, c):
   return (a * np.sin(b *(x-h)) + c)

params, extras= curve_fit(func, x, y)
plt.plot(x, func(x, params[0], params[1], params[2], params[3]), c='r')
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.xlim(55007, 55010)
plt.ylim(.98,1.02)
plt.title("Binary Star System")
plt.xlabel("MJD")
plt.ylabel("Flux")
plt.legend(["fit", "data"])
plt.show()
```

X and y are NumPy arrays. Is there a curve-fit function for sinusoidal graphs?  No matter what curve-fitting code I try, I always end up with a somewhat horizontal line and I'm not sure why. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's a typical value for b?  Is it possible that x=(55007, 55010) is a tiny portion of the curve?

Comment: If you don't pass the `p0` argument to `curve_fit` specifying the initial values for your function parameters then these are automatically initialized to be all 1. This seems like it would be a bad initial guess, so `curve_fit` will probably fail to converge on a sensible solution. Eyeballing the lower plot, I reckon `a` should be about 0.25, `b` should be about pi/2, `h` should be something like 3.5, and `c` should be about 0.8.

Comment: @ali_m I've played around with the values in p0, and I'm still getting a horizontal-ish line. I had the values in the order of a, b, h, c. I had p0 as a SciPy array and called p0 in curve_fit. Is it possible that the file is just too large?

Comment: @StephenTerry Yes, the complete data set is quite large.

Comment: I limited the data in the array prior to graphing and it worked! The p0 argument was optional. Thanks for the help.